# What can I do to debug the .filter() method?

Tags: protractor

I'm testing a webpage that has a list of information, a list of cards.  So, in order to select the correct card using a method, I have the following:

```
getCardByName(expectedName: string): CardActions {
    console.log("WatchActions: Getting Card of " + expectedName);
    let majorCount = 1;

    /*
     * watchPageObject.cards: ElementArrayFinder = this.tab.$$('card-watch');
     */
    let theCard = this.watchPageObject.cards.filter(function (elCard, index) {
        return elCard.getText().then(
            function (name) {
                name = name.substr(0, name.search('\nAge:'));
                console.log(majorCount++ + "-" + index + ") " + name + 
                            " = " + (name == expectedName));
                return name == expectedName;
            });
    }).first();

    return new CardActions(new CardPageObject(theCard));
}
```

The obvious flaw is obvious, if there are two or more matches, the second match is never referenced. I'll cross that logical bridge when or if necessary.

The method works properly and I get the return values I'm expecting.  However, the script seems to take longer than expected, and the console logging bears it out as it shows (names are fake):

```
1-0) KERGER, FEYSAL = false
2-1) JENNINGS, JEWELLAN = false
3-2) CRAVEN, LILLARD = true
4-3) HORSTMANN, GREG = false
5-4) MEUSA, FRANKLIN = false
6-5) LAURITO, RANDOLPH = false
7-6) JHANSON, LORENE = false
8-0) KERGER, FEYSAL = false
9-1) JENNINGS, JEWELLAN = false
10-2) CRAVEN, LILLARD = true
...
90-5) LAURITO, RANDOLPH = false
91-6) JHANSON, LORENE = false
92-0) KERGER, FEYSAL = false
93-1) JENNINGS, JEWELLAN = false
94-2) CRAVEN, LILLARD = true
95-3) HORSTMANN, GREG = false
96-4) MEUSA, FRANKLIN = false
97-5) LAURITO, RANDOLPH = false
98-6) JHANSON, LORENE = false
```

What can I do to figure out why the filter finds it necessary to loop through the list of 7 cards 14 times?

I was hoping to come up with a generic example using a public page, but that test worked flawlessly.

FWIW: Here's the example I came up with (code above is typescript, code below is javascript)

```
describe('Test and show the progression of the .filter() method', function() {

    beforeAll(function() {
        browser.get("http://www.angulartodo.com/");
    });

    afterAll(function() {
        browser.close();
    });

    it('add values to todos', function(done) {
                // Add a number of "todos".
        var todos = ["Deposit Check", "Purchase Groceries", "Pick Up Kids"];

        todos.forEach(function(todo) {
            element(by.css('.todos form > input')).sendKeys(todo).then(function() {
                element(by.css('.todos form > button')).click();
            });
        });
        done();

    });

    it('display the map progressions', function(done) {
        var listItems = element.all(by.css('.todos ul li'));
        var majorCount = 1;
        listItems.filter(function(el, index) {
            return el.element(by.css('span:nth-child(2)')).getText().then(function(text) {
                console.log(index + ") " + text);
                return text.includes("Up");
            });
        }).getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text);
        });
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you show how is `this.watchPageObject.cards` defined? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question to include the info, but in case it gets missed, here is how watchPageObject.cards is defined: `readonly tab: ElementFinder = $('#md-tab-content-0-0'); readonly cards: ElementArrayFinder = this.tab.$$('card-watch');`

Comment: Could you put the following into your test: `this.watchPageObject.cards.count().then(console.log);`? What count do you see printed on the console? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this matters. Someone added an 8th card to the test page, and now the filter runs 17 times.

Comment: Well, it looks like you are going over all the `.cards` and filter them based on the text.

Comment: I updated the initial console line to be: `this.watchPageObject.cards.count().then(count => console.log("WatchActions: Getting Card of " + expectedName + ".\nSearching " + count + " cards."));` The result I get is: `WatchActions: Getting Card of CRAVEN, LILLARD. Searching 7 cards.`